# Why object value can not assign to an union type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Say, if I have two union type in TypeScript, for example:

```js
const a = 1;
const b = 2;

type AB = typeof a | typeof b;
type AABB = 'aa' | 'bb';

type Test = AB | AABB;

const obj = {
  a: 'aa',
  b: 'bb'
}

const t1: Test = 'aa';
const t2: Test = obj.a;
```

'aa' can assign to t1, but `obj.a` can not assign to t2, why?

Comment: I just corrected your term. It should be `union type` (not `intersection type`)

Answer (score 2):

Because your `obj`'s type is:

```
const obj: {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}
```

The object properties are interpreted by TS to be *just strings*, not *specific* strings. So `obj.a` is a string, but a `Test` is a (union of) *specific* strings, so it's not assignable.

Change to

```
const obj = {
  a: 'aa',
  b: 'bb'
} as const;
```

so that the properties aren't widened, and your code will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to the answer from @CertainPerformance, `as const` is called a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), and makes the typescript compiler interpet all literals with in object as their narrowed, readonly types.

To explain, for your case:

```
const obj = {
  a: 'aa',
  b: 'bb'
};

type Inferred = {
  a: string,
  b: string
};
```

Alternatively:

```
const obj = {
  a: 'aa',
  b: 'bb'
} as const;

type Inferred = {
  readonly a: 'aa',
  readonly b: 'bb'
};
```